# Does double negation distribute over disjunction intuitionistically?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, intuitionistic-logic

Does the following equivalence

$$\lnot \lnot (A \lor B) \leftrightarrow (\lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B)$$

hold in propositional intuitionistic logic? And in propositional minimal logic? (In propositional classical logic this is obvious since $A \leftrightarrow \lnot\lnot A$ is classically provable.)

Actually I have a proof that $(\lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B) \to \lnot \lnot (A \lor B)$
holds in propositional minimal logic, so I'm interested in the converse implication:

$$\lnot \lnot (A \lor B) \to (\lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B)$$

If it is minimally or/and intuitionistically provable, I would like a (reference to a) direct proof in natural deduction-style.

Comment: Can you post axiom sets/rules of inference here?  I know I can find intuitionistic axioms which seem standard, but I'm not so sure about minimal logic.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: The list of axioms for (first-order and then, in particular, propositional) intuitionistic logic is available for example [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/). 
The list of axioms for (first-order and then, in particular, propositional) minimal logic is just obtained by the list above removing the axiom $\lnot A \to (A \to B)$ (ex-falso-quodlibet).
However, I would prefer a direct proof in natural deduction-style (if any), if it is possible.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco A good rule of thumb is that to prove a disjunction intuitionistically, you'll need to be able to prove one of its disjuncts.  (I'm excluding cases like $A \to (B \lor C)$ (where you could try to prove $A$ first, and then use conditional elimination) and $A \land (B \lor C)$ (where you could use conjunction elimination).)  From the left side, I don't think that you can infer either $\lnot\lnot A$ or $\lnot\lnot B$, so I don't think you'll be able to get the right side. You can get from the right side to the left, though (as you've shown).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\lnot \lnot (A \lor B) \to (\lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B)$ is not intuitionistically acceptable. One way of seeing this is by considering the Heyting algebra whose elements are the open subsets of the unit interval $[0, 1] \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ under the subspace topology, with $A \lor B = A \cup B$, $A \to B = \mathsf{int}(A^c\cup B)$ and $\bot = \emptyset$  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra). In this Heyting algebra, $\lnot\lnot A$ is the interior of the closure of $A$ and $A \to B$ is $\top$ iff $A \subseteq B$. Hence if $A = [0, 1/2)$ and $B = (1/2, 1]$, $\lnot \lnot (A \lor B) = [0, 1]$ while $\lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B = [0, 1] \mathop{\backslash} \{1/2\}$ and $\lnot \lnot (A \lor B) \to (\lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B)$ is not $\top$.

Comment: Just in case the OP is more familiar with Kripke models than with topological ones, here's a Kripke counterexample. The underlying partially ordered set consists of $a,b,c$ with $c<a$ and $c<b$ while $a$ and $b$ are incomparable. Let $A$ be true only at $a$ and let $B$ be true only at $b$. Then $\neg\neg A$ and $\neg\neg B$ are also true only at $a$ and $b$, respectively, so their disjunction is true at $a$ and $b$ but not at $c$. On the other hand, $\neg\neg(A\lor B)$ is true everywhere, including $c$.

Comment: @RobArthan: Thank you, your answer is very clear!

Comment: @AndreasBlass: also your answer is very clear, thank you!

Comment: My topology is pretty bad, are you certain $\lnot \lnot (A \lor B) = [0, 1]$  ? I am getting $(0, 1)$ according to the definition of interior I'm finding.  The third bullet point here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)#Examples  .  Also how are you defining $\top$ ? Thanks

Comment: I should have made it clearer that we are working with the  [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) on $[0, 1]$ here. $[0, 1]$ is open in that topology. Hence $\mathrm{Int}([0, 1]) = [0, 1]$. $\top$ is the open set $[0, 1]$ (it's not open viewed as a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ but it is open in the subspace topology on $[0, 1]$).

Comment: @RobArthan Ok thanks that's a little beyond my ability still.

Answer (score 6):

By substituting $¬A$ for $B$ in $¬¬(A∨B)→(¬¬A∨¬¬B)$ we can easily derive  weak excluded middle $¬¬A∨¬A$ which is certainly not intuitionistically acceptable. Hence $¬¬(A∨B)→(¬¬A∨¬¬B)$ is also not acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Before getting down to technicalities, in cases like this it is worth first thinking informally. So, should we *expect* $\lnot \lnot (A \lor B) \to (\lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B)$ to hold intuitionistically, given an informal BHK-style understanding of the connectives? If we are in a position to rule out being able to refute $A \lor B$, does that mean we must already be in a position to rule out being able to refute $A$ or alternatively in a position to to rule out being able to refute $B$?

Intuitively(!) not. So that gives us a motivation for expecting the given wff to fail as an intuitionistic theorem, and hence to look for a Kripke counter model. And as Andreas Blass shows, once you start looking for a suitable model, given the constraints, you'll quickly land on one!