# Identity and substitution in Intuitionistic Logic

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I am a beginner in mathematical logic. I have a basic question about identity propositions in intuitionistic logic. For example, from $(*)$ and $(**)$:
$$\Gamma\vdash a=b\quad\quad(*)\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\Gamma\vdash P(a)\quad\quad(**)$$
we shall deduce that $\Gamma\vdash P(b)$ also holds. But what if we have $(***)$?
$$\Gamma\vdash \neg\neg(a=b)\quad\quad(***).$$
My question is: from $(**)$ and $(***)$, shall we conclude $\Gamma\vdash P(b)$ or $\Gamma\vdash\neg\neg P(b)$?

I don't know how to handle identity propositions because I have not met these in my textbook (von Plato, 2014). I would appreciate it a lot if anyone can answer my question and if possible provide some useful references for handling identity propositions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In classical logic we have $\vdash \neg \neg A \to A$, so from $\Gamma \vdash \neg \neg (a=b)$ we can derive $\Gamma \vdash (a=b)$, then with $\Gamma \vdash P(a)$ conclude $\Gamma \vdash P(b)$.

Comment: See page 85 for the way to derive double negation elimination from DN rule (the rule of Indirect Proof, page 81)

Comment: Sorry, I forget to include the condition that it's in intuitionistic logic. Now it's added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I.** From $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg (a = b)$ and $\Gamma \vdash P(a)$, can we conclude $\Gamma \vdash P(b)$?

No. In the general case, $\Gamma \vdash P(b)$ does not follow from $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg(a = b)$ and $\Gamma \vdash P(a)$.

Assume that we could conclude $\Gamma \vdash P(b)$ from $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg(a = b)$ and $\Gamma \vdash P(a)$ for any context $\Gamma$ and formula $P$. Then in particular this would work for $P(x) \leftrightarrow a = x$. We'd have $\Gamma \vdash P(a)$ by the reflexivity of equality, so we would be able to conclude $\Gamma \vdash P(b)$, that is, $\Gamma \vdash a = b$. This would mean that equality is always stable under double-negation, i.e. that $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg (a = b) \rightarrow a = b$ is provable in every context.

However, we can construct theories (models, topoi) where equality is not $\neg\neg$-stable, e.g. any model of [Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis).

> **II.** From $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg (a = b)$ and $\Gamma \vdash P(a)$, can we conclude $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg P(b)$?

We can always do this. The trick is to realize that [double negation distributes over implication, even in intuitionistic logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753752/does-double-negation-distribute-over-implication-intuitionistically).

Since $\Gamma \vdash a = b \rightarrow (P(a) \rightarrow P(b))$ is provable, we can introduce a double negation to get $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg (a = b \rightarrow P(a) \rightarrow P(b))$, and distribute the double negations to get $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg (a = b) \rightarrow \neg\neg P(a) \rightarrow \neg\neg P(b)$. Since we already know $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg (a = b)$, we can conclude that $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg P(a) \rightarrow \neg\neg P(b)$. Similarly, we already know $\Gamma \vdash P(a)$, from which it follows that $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg P(a)$. Putting everything together we get $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg P(b)$, which was to be shown.